# Figuring out return type of closure

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm having troubles figuring out the type signature of the `fn filter` function in following example.

**The Node and Descendant definition is just there for syntax . It's not meant to do anything!**

```
use std::iter::Filter;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
   s: &'a str,
}

pub struct Descendants<'a>{
    iter: Node<'a>
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Descendants<'a> {
    type Item = Node<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Node<'a>> {
        Some(Node {s: self.iter.s})
    }
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    pub fn descendants(&self) -> Descendants<'a> {
        Descendants{ iter: Node{s: self.s} }  
    }

    pub fn filter(&self, criteria: &str) -> Filter<Descendants<'a>, fn(&'a Node<'a>)->bool > {
        self.descendants()
            .filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let doc = Node{s: "str"};

}
```

[(Playground link)](http://is.gd/GCJdih)

The error I get is following:

```
<anon>:27:28: 27:34 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<anon>:27             .filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
                                     ^~~~~~
<anon>:27:21: 27:43 error: mismatched types:
 expected `fn(&Node<'_>) -> bool`,
    found `[closure <anon>:27:21: 27:43]`
(expected fn pointer,
    found closure) [E0308]
<anon>:27             .filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:27:14: 27:44 error: type mismatch: the type `fn(&Node<'_>) -> bool` implements the trait `core::ops::FnMut<(&Node<'_>,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r Node<'_>,)>` is required (expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter ) [E0281]
<anon>:27             .filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:27:14: 27:44 error: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <fn(&Node<'_>) -> bool as core::ops::FnOnce<(&'r Node<'_>,)>>::Output == bool`:
 expected bound lifetime parameter ,
    found concrete lifetime [E0271]
<anon>:27             .filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 4 previous errors
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

When I as per this question [Correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator) I tried to replace `pub fn filter(&self, criteria: &str) -> Filter<Descendants<'a>, fn(&'a Node<'a>)->bool >` with `pub fn filter(&self, criteria: &str) -> ()` I get

```
<anon>:26:9: 27:44 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::iter::Filter<Descendants<'_>, [closure <anon>:27:21: 27:43]>`
```

What I'm supposed to replace `closure` with?

Alternatively, if it's too hard and finicky to return a `Filter`, how do I write the `Wrapper` for `fn filter()` return type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I clearly remember that this was answered before a few times (I even wrote about it in an answer [a few minutes before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641982/788207)) but I can't find a link now, so here it goes.

The problem with your code is that you use a closure as `filter()` argument:

```rust
.filter(|node| node.s == "meh")
```

Unboxed closures in Rust are implemented as anonymous types which, naturally, can't be named, so there is *no* way to write a signature of a function which returns an iterator which uses a closure. That's what the error message you're getting is about:

```
 expected `fn(&Node<'_>) -> bool`,
    found `[closure <anon>:27:21: 27:43]`
(expected fn pointer,
    found closure) [E0308]
```

There are several ways around this, one of them is to use trait objects:

```rust
pub fn filter<'b>(&'b self, criteria: &'b str) -> Box<Iterator<Item=Node<'a>+'b>>
{
    Box::new(self.descendants().filter(move |node| node.s == criteria))
}
```

Given that your closure has a non-empty environment, this is the only way for your code to work. If your closure didn't capture anything, you could use a static function whose type can be written out:

```rust
pub fn filter(&self) -> Filter<Descendants<'a>, fn(&Node<'a>) -> bool> {
    fn filter_fn<'b>(node: &Node<'b>) -> bool {
        node.s == "meh"
    }
    self.descendants().filter(filter_fn)
}
```

Comment: Side note, what if `filter_fn`/closure had to take another parameter? Like say `Vec<i32>`.

Comment: Neither `filter_fn()` nor closure cannot take an additional parameter because it won't correspond to `filter()` signature anymore. You can *capture* `Vec<i32>` in a closure, like `move |node| node.s.len() == vector.head().unwrap_or(12) as usize`, but it won't be different from capturing `criteria` as in my first example.