# Is it possible to return a Rust closure that returns a closure without using a Box?

Tags: rust, closures

It is easy to wrap the inner closure inside a `Box`:

```
fn add1() -> impl Fn(i32) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    |x| Box::new(|y| x + y)
}
```

But is it necessary to use a `Box`? In the following code:

```
fn add2() -> ?? {
    |x: i32| move |y: i32| x + y
}
```

Can I replace `??` with something to make the code type check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. As you are already aware, `impl Trait` is the mechanism to return an instance of a trait without boxing.

If you try to extend this:

```
fn add2() -> impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    |x| |y| x + y
}
```

The compiler tells you:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:30
  |
9 | fn add2() -> impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From the `impl Trait` RFC, emphasis mine:

> `impl Trait` may only be written within the return type of a
>   freestanding or inherent-impl function, not in trait definitions or
>   any non-return type position. They may also not appear in the return
>   type of closure traits or function pointers, unless these are
>   themselves part of a legal return type.
>
> - **Eventually, we will want to allow the feature to be used within traits**

The return type of a closure is an *associated type* of the closure trait:

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [How do I return an instance of a trait from a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30661046/155423)