# Creating a cyclic Tokio stream connected to a shared state

Tags: rust, stream, rust-tokio

I am running into a problem that I do not really understand and hoped
that somebody might be able to see what I have misunderstood.

The problem is quite straightforward: I have a global state (shared
between several tasks) and want to have an infinite cycle over a
vector in the global state. I will then zip that with an interval
stream and hence get a regular emission of the next value in the
stream.

If the vector in the state changes, the inifinite stream should just
reload the vector and start reading from the new one instead, and
discard the old array.

Here is the code that I've gotten this far, and the questions are at
the end of the post.

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::{Async, Poll};
use std::iter::Cycle;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::timer::Interval;
```

We define a global state that hold an array that can be
updated. Whenever the array is updated, we will step the version and
set the array.

```rust
struct State<T> {
    version: u32,
    array: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> State<T> {
    fn new(array: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            version: 0,
            array: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, array: Vec<T>) {
        self.version += 1;
        self.array = array;
    }
}
```

Now, we create an stream over the state. When initialized, it will
read the array and version from the state and store it and then keep
an instance of `std::iter::Cycle` internally that will cycle over the
array.

```rust
struct StateStream<I> {
    state: Arc<Mutex<State<I::Item>>>,
    version: u32,
    iter: Cycle<I>,
}

impl<I> StateStream<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    fn new(state: Arc<Mutex<State<I::Item>>>) -> Self {
        let (version, array) = {
            let locked_state = state.lock().unwrap();
            (locked_state.version, locked_state.array)
        };

        Self {
            state: state,
            version: version,
            iter: array.iter().cycle(),
        }
    }
}
```

We now implement the stream for the `StateStream`. With each poll, it
will check if the version of the state changed, and if it did, reload
the array and version.

We will then take the next item from the iterator and return that.

```rust
impl<I> Stream for StateStream<I>
where
    I: Iterator + Clone,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        let locked_state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        if locked_state.version > self.version {
            self.iter = locked_state.array.clone().iter().cycle();
            self.version = locked_state.version;
        }
        Ok(Async::Ready(self.iter.next()))
    }
}
```

The main program looks like this. I do not update the vector here, but
that is not important for the case at hand.

```rust
fn main() {
    let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(State::new(vec![2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13])));
    let primes = StateStream::new(state)
        .take(20)
        .zip(
            Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(500))
                .map_err(|err| println!("Error: {}", err)),
        )
        .for_each(|(number, instant)| {
            println!("fire; number={}, instant={:?}", number, instant);
            Ok(())
        });
    tokio::run(primes);
}
```

When compiling this, I get the following errors:

```
cargo run --example cycle_stream_shared
   Compiling tokio-testing v0.1.0 (/home/mats/crates/tokio-examples)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> examples/cycle_stream_shared.rs:66:19
   |
66 |             iter: array.iter().cycle(),
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::slice::Iter`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::iter::Cycle<I>`
              found type `std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'_, <I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> examples/cycle_stream_shared.rs:81:25
   |
81 |             self.iter = locked_state.array.clone().iter().cycle();
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::slice::Iter`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::iter::Cycle<I>`
              found type `std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'_, <I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item>>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: Could not compile `tokio-testing`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Now, the error and the explanation says that the concrete type is not
possible to derive, but in this case, I am using the generic struct
`Cycle<I>` and expect `I` to be instantiated to `std::slice::Iter<'_,
I::Item>`. Since `std::slice::Iter` has implemented `Iterator` and, the type have implemented all necessary traits to match.

Some answers to similar questions exist, but nothing that seems to
match this case:

- [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic
  struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551177/expected-type-parameter-error-in-the-constructor-of-a-generic-struct) is showing that the types do not match (same
  as the explanation gives) because the generic struct definition allow any type, but the construction require a specific type.

  In this case, we are using a generic type `Cycle<I>`, where `I` should implement the `Iterator` trait, and try to use a type `std::slice::Iter<..>` that *does* implement `Iterator`.
- [How do I return an instance of a trait from a
  method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661046/how-do-i-return-an-instance-of-a-trait-from-a-method) talk about how to return an arbitrary type
  matching a trait, which is not the case here.

The other questions are mostly referring to these two, or variations
of these.

**Update:** Changed it to be a generic type to demonstrate that it still does not work.

Comment: Why don't u use: `StateStream<T, I> where I: Iterator<Item = T>`

Comment: It is possible, if I want a generic `StateStream`, but in this case I made the question simpler by using a concrete type.

Comment: Your question could be much smaller. It boils down to the fact that the compiler cannot infer `I`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551177/expected-type-parameter-error-in-the-constructor-of-a-generic-struct)

Comment: But it is a generic struct is `Cycle<I>` and it tries to match `Cycle<std::slice::Iter<i32>>`, which can't it deduce `I` to be `std::slice::Iter<i32>`?

Comment: I have referenced that question in the post.