# Is it possible for main function to return any kind of error that implements Debug trait?

Tags: error-handling, rust, traits

I have recently discovered that:

> In Rust 2018 you can instead let your `#[test]`s and `main` functions return a `Result`:
>
> ```
> use std::fs::File;
>
> fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
>     let f = File::open("bar.txt")?;
>     Ok(())
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, if say the file doesn't exist and there is an `Err(err)` somewhere, then `main` will exit with an error code (not 0) and print out a `Debug` representation of `err`.
>
> Source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/question-mark-in-main-and-tests.html

However, what return type should I specify if there is more than one type of error returned in my `main` function? Since an error is used just to print out its `Debug` representation, I thought that it may be possible to return `Result<(), dyn Debug>`. Unfortunately, the code below:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error1;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error2;

fn do_something() -> Result<(), Error1> {}
fn do_something_else() -> Result<(), Error2> {}

fn main() -> Result<(), dyn Debug> {
    do_something()?;
    do_something_else()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
36 | / fn main() -> Result<(), dyn Debug> {
37 | |     do_something()?;
38 | |     do_something_else()?;
39 | |     Ok(())
40 | | }
   | |_^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::fmt::Debug + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required by `std::result::Result`
```

Is there any workaround here? Or is the only solution to map all the function calls to one kind kind of error?

Comment: first look how to return a dyn type in ANY normal function, main doesn't differs https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=220a415817a1bb756c99ef409c0ec02f

Comment: Thank you. To be fair, I have tried appending `.map_err(|e| Box::new(e))` to function calls, but it didn't work without casting with `as _` and resulted in the following error: `the trait std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<Error1>> is not implemented for std::boxed::Box<dyn std::fmt::Debug>`.

Comment: + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661046/how-do-i-return-an-instance-of-a-trait-from-a-method