# How can I iterate over the indices of a generic collection that implements Index and IntoIterator?

Tags: generics, collections, rust, traits

I want to implement a small directed graph trait for any generic collection `C` that implements `std::ops::Index` and `std::iter::IntoIterator`. I want the collection to represent the nodes of the graph. Each node is represented by its index into `C`, which could be a `usize` index into a `Vec` or a `String` key into a `HashMap`.
I don't know if this is the best approach to a graph library, but I also want to learn about Rust, generic traits and the standard library of Rust.

At some points of my implementation I need to iterate over all indices of a `C` instance. The only method I have found to do this is the `enumerate` function, but this implements only a `usize` counter for an iterator and not my generic type, so it would work for `Vec`, but not for `HashMap`.

Here is what the implementation looks like using `enumerate`. The `nodes` and `children` function are required, `children` returns the adjacency information of the graph. To get all the predecessors using the `parents` function, I need to iterate over the indices of the generic container type.

```rust
pub trait SimpleGraph {
    /// type used as an index to refer to nodes.
    type I: Eq + std::hash::Hash;

    /// container type for the nodes
    type C: std::ops::Index<Self::I> + std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = Self::I>;

    /// returns a reference to the node container.
    fn nodes(&self) -> &Self::C;

    /// gets the indices of the children of a node with index `index`.
    fn children(&self, index: Self::I) -> Vec<Self::I>;

    /// gets all ancestors of a node (not very efficient...)
    fn parents(&self, i: Self::I) -> Vec<Self::I> {
        let mut res = Vec::<Self::I>::new();
        let nodes = self.nodes();
        for (idx, _) in nodes.into_iter().enumerate() {
            let children = self.children(idx);
            for child_idx in children {
                if child_idx == i {
                    res.push(idx);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

This gives me the not very surprising compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:19:42
   |
19 |             let children = self.children(idx);
   |                                          ^^^ expected associated type, found usize
   |
   = note: expected type `<Self as SimpleGraph>::I`
              found type `usize`
```

One *ugly* solution would be to add another required method `indices` that returns a list of indices and then iterate over this list, but this would not be very user friendly and seems like an unnecessary step for any of the `std::collections` that implement both `std::ops::Index` and `std::iter::IntoIterator`. I would rather overwrite the `enumerate` function in a generic way.

How would I code this in a clean and generic way?

Comment: `IntoIterator::into_iter` takes `self`; you can't call `.into_iter()` on a value of `&C` (``cannot move out of `*nodes` which is behind a shared reference``). I think you probably need to rethink this a bit -- `IntoIterator` only lets you *consume* the collection, not iterate over it in-place.

Comment: Thanks @trentcl, I missed that! In the end I guess I don't really need the `IntoIterator` trait, as long as I can iterate over the *indices* of the collection somehow. I just don't know how I can achieve this generically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:

- Minimal example in a [Github Repo](https://github.com/joergbrech/graphtest/tree/MWE)
- Minimal example in a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=033fab2186cf7ca204ad7fa8978489fe)

## Explanation

I realized that I wished `Index` provided an `enumerate` method to enumerate indices and the items behind the index of the collection. So with the help of the accepted answer [Using generic iterators instead of specific list types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630810/using-generic-iterators-instead-of-specific-list-types) I implemented a supertrait of `Index` that provides this method.

### Step 1: Define a new `Enumerate` struct and implement `Iterator` for it

```rust
pub struct Enumerate<IndexIter, ItemIter> {
    index: IndexIter,
    item: ItemIter,
}

/// implements the [`Iterator`] trait for the new struct
impl<IndexIter, ItemIter> Iterator for Enumerate<IndexIter, ItemIter>
where
    IndexIter: Iterator,
    ItemIter: Iterator,
{
    type Item = (IndexIter::Item, ItemIter::Item);

    /// returns the next iterator
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(IndexIter::Item, ItemIter::Item)> {
        self.index.next().map(|idx| {
            // CAUTION! We need to make sure that the index and item iterators are ordered consistently.
            // We are really just incrementing two iterators simultaneously here...
            (idx, self.item.next().unwrap())
        })
    }
}
```

### Step 2: Define a supertrait for `Index` that adds the `enumerate` method

```rust
/// trait for implementing over the indices of collections that implement [`std::ops::Index`].
/// 
/// It adds the enumerate function that returns an `Enumerate<IndexIter,ItemIter>` as an iterator.
pub trait SuperIndex<'a, Idx>: std::ops::Index<Idx> {
    type IndexIter: Iterator<Item = Idx>;
    type ItemIter: Iterator;

    /// enumerates over the indices and items of a collection
    fn enumerate(&'a self) -> Enumerate<Self::IndexIter, Self::ItemIter>;
}
```

### Step 3: Implement the supertrait for the collections I want to use

#### Implementation for `Vec`

```rust
/// implement the [`SuperIndex`] trait for [`Vec<T>`]
impl<'a, T: 'a> SuperIndex<'a, usize> for Vec<T> {
    type IndexIter = std::ops::Range<usize>;
    type ItemIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn enumerate(&'a self) -> Enumerate<Self::IndexIter, Self::ItemIter> {
        Enumerate {
            index: 0..self.len(),
            item: self.iter(),
        }
    }
}
```

#### Implementation for `HashMap`

```rust
/// implement the [`SuperIndex`] trait for [`HashMap<K, V, S>`]
impl<'a, K: 'a, V: 'a, S> SuperIndex<'a, &'a K> for std::collections::HashMap<K, V, S>
where
    K: Eq + std::hash::Hash,
    S: std::hash::BuildHasher,
{
    type IndexIter = std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'a, K, V>;
    type ItemIter = std::collections::hash_map::Values<'a, K, V>;

    fn enumerate(&'a self) -> Enumerate<Self::IndexIter, Self::ItemIter> {
        Enumerate {
            index: self.keys(),
            item: self.values(),
        }
    }
}
```

## Discussion

Now I can enumerate the index and value for any kind of collection that implements `SuperIndex` and `index` does not have to be a `usize`:

```rust
for (index, item) in c.enumerate() {
    assert_eq!(&c[index], item);
}
```

This implementation does what I want and I can't think of any alternatives, but it has a few minor pitfalls:

- `SuperIndex` indices cannot be quite as generic as the ones for `Index`, e.g. slices are not allowed.
- We need to explicitly implement `SuperIndex` for each collection.
- In each implementation, we must make sure that the two iterators are ordered consistently.

If there is anything off in my implementation please let me know! It seems to work fine, but I only understand half of what I am doing.

Comment: You can replace your `Enumerate` struct with `std::iter::Zip`, and you get a fuller implementation of the same kind of iterator. Though no panic if the indices are longer than the values, that would work differently.  Now this answer maybe doesn't need to be a full solution, but another option is to leave the `Enumerate` thing as an associated type, so that collections can provide their own optimized version if possible. They can always fall back to `Zip`.  Example of that: `HashMap`'s enumeration iterator is just its `.iter()`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @bluss! [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fb617f4d2f68fa387b9cb67eb2dc417) is the implementation using `std::iter::Zip` instead of `Enumerate`, its much more concise. I am not sure if I can replace the `Enumerate`/`Zip` output with another associated type, because I need to bind the `Iterator::Item` type of the `IndexIter` to the `Idx` type.